Mapping this problem from solving the Minimum Cost Flow to solving the Max Flow problem
I'm trying to implement the algorithm described in FD21.
In particular, this is the optimization problem (problem 2 in the paper).
Find the liability matrix $M$ of the obligation network $M$ such that its Grandsum function $\mu$ is minimum:
\begin{equation}
\min \mu(M) = \min \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n M_{ij}
\end{equation}
subject to the constraints:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n M_{ki} - \sum_{k=1}^n M_{ik} = b_i \qquad \forall i \in {N}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0 \leq M_{ij} \leq L_{ij} \qquad \forall i,j \in {N}.
\end{equation}
The paper maps this problem to a Minimum Cost Flow problem on a graph. Their proposed implementation assignes by default a cost of 1 to every edge in the graph.
Intuitively, it seems to me that, since you are not using the cost, there might be a more efficient graph-theory algorithm to solve this problem. For example by leveraging the Max Flow algorithm. But I am struggling to find one.

The Min-Cost Flow Problem is a special case of the Max Flow Problem (see under Related Problems and this), in that if one sets all the costs of the edges in the network to zero, then one can deploy a Min-Cost Flow algorithm to find the shortest path between nodes and that would relate to Maximum Flow. They cite Király and Kovács's paper covering various Min-Cost Flow Problem applications and multiple Min-Cost Flow algorithms.
Here's a related answer to a similar question
